# How to prevent broken build in master using gerrit?

Tags: git, build, workflow, gerrit

Gerrit workflow was invented to make builds pass before the failure is introduced to master. This prevents most of the failures, but master can still be broken.

Consider this:

- Dev A introduces a feature 1 with a test and get it merged
- Dev B introduces a feature 2 that is incompatible with feature 1, but does so that there are no merge conflicts => merged
- Dev C finds out that the master build is broken.

How to prevent this from happening?

here's a timeline:

```
master
  .-> feature 1 with a test1 => build passing
  .-> feature 2 that causes test1 to fail => build passing because there is no dependency on feature 1
  |
<-. merge feature 1
<-. merge feature 2 => no conflicts
  . master is broken
```

**Example**

code before feature 1 and feature 2:

```
# file: code.js
function code() {
  return true;
}
```

test added in feature 1:

```
# file: test_code.js
function test_code() {
  assert(test_code() == true);
}
```

test added in feature 2:

```
# file: test_feature.js
function test_feature() {
  assert(test_code() == false);
}
```

code changed in feature 2:

```
# file: code.js
function code() {
  return false;
}
```

As you see, there is no conflicts.

Comment: Can you just give an example? because i can not imagine.. what do you mean "feature 1 with a test" also please add the time when features are submitted to master from review and pushed to review

Comment: Added submit timeline.

Comment: @HiB
It's just a feature that have some tests.
Feature 2 is a feature that causes feature  1 to fail.
The failure not catched because  feature 1 is not yet on master at the time of feature 2 review.

Answer (score -1):

If Dev B is doing the merge. It's their responsibility to run the tests and make sure they still pass.

When using a classical Gerrit workflow (i.e. Gerrit doing the merge), I'm pretty sure that Gerrit will require you to rebase your change before merging it; All I remember of that situation is when there is a conflict, then I'm required to execute the rebase locally, but in that case if the tests are failing and I somehow forget to run them, Jenkins picks it up, and run the tests on my rebased change and immediately flag my CL with a -1 (Verified).

Comment: > Gerrit will require you to rebase your change before merging it; <

Not always. Only when there is a conflict. I'm talking about the situation when there is no conflict.